# Writing to a row in a CSV with data already in the row apart from one column in that row and inserting data into that empty coloumn

Tags: python, csv

Currently trying to add a single item of data to a row in a CSV but it keeps adding it underneath the correct fieldvalue. Do I need to use a float? Really unsure here. Any help would be appreciated.
This code is basically trying to miss out current data and then insert a variable into the empty csv column in the row.

```
writer.writerow([""]+[""]+[""]+[""]+[""]+[""]+[""]+[""]+[""]+[""]+[""]+[""]+[""]+[cweight])
```

Comment: I think you need to give a lot more context. If I were into closing questions, I would vote to close this one as "unclear what you are asking".

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you have the following type of csv data

```
Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4
Value1,Value2,,Value4
```

And you would like to use a .writerow() function to make the following

```
Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4
Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4
```

But instead, your result keeps being

```
Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4
Value1,Value2,,Value4
,,Value3,
```

If this is the case, then you could use a csv.reader to read in the value, assign it to the correct index position, and csv.writer to write the result out to a new file.

```
import csv

# Open the input and output csv files
with open(example_input.csv, "rb") as csvFileInput:
    with open(example_output.csv, "wb") as csvFileOutput:

# Set the reader on the input csv
# Set the writer on the output csv
    reader = csv.reader(csvFileInput)
    writer = csv.writer(csvFileOutput)

# read the first row and assign the field names from the reader to a variable
    fields = reader.next()

# write the field names to the new output csv.
    writer.writerow(fields)

# Read the next line with data values from the input csv
    row = reader.next()

# read the index position of the empty (or replaceable) data value from input csv
# Assign the row value to a new value
# Write the new row to the output csv
    row[2] = 'Value3'
    writer.writerow(row)
```